# Finding the line count of source files as a table in nushell

Tags: nushell

I'm very early in trying to learn nushell, sorry! … I'd like to build a table with all the recursively found ".swift" source files in a folder, and then append an additional column that contains their (computed) line count.

- I've used [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1720919/nushell-list-all-files-recursively) which has an approach to finding all files with `ls **/*.swift`.
- I've used [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1722579/nushell-add-computed-column-to-table) which has an approach to adding a computed column to a table with `insert`.

This has lead me to try out:

```
ls **/*.swift | insert lineCount { wc -l $in.name }
```

However, this does not seem to work. It's printing a lot of stuff, but it seems to be chunks of table output interspersed with chunks of `wc` output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using native Nushell commands - no need for `wc` which might not be available on other platforms (like Windows):

```
ls **/*.py | select name | insert linecount { open $in.name | lines | length }
```

(I'm working on `.py` files here)

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Windows Terminal showing the results of the above command]